# how to add blackberry library into blackberry-eclipse-plugin project?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

[image: Error]

when i try to include blackberry library into project i see that happen nothing happen and error like pic
where i try this:-
preverify it by

```
preverify.exe -classpath [JDE_PATH]\lib\net_rim_api.jar myjarfile.jar 

and try this
preverify.exe -classpath [JDE_PATH]\lib\net_rim_api.jar; myjarfile.jar

myjarfile.jar in bin folder
```

after that i but it into my project in lib source folder as pic and check order and export checkbox true 

- i have ksoap2-j2me-core-prev-2.1.2.jar already preverify but the only difference that "myjarfile" is blackberry library and the "ksoap" is j2me
please help

any new answers???

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the compiler compliance level to 1.4 in project properties ( in java compiler ).

Comment: u can tell me how to create blackberry library and how to include it in another project ??? please step by step

Comment: @Henawey ... Were you able to do it ? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Mayank in the end i can't do it, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the source for this library, you can follow the details I have in another answer:

- [BlackBerry - use own JAR file in own project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9978353/383414)

You might find something useful on that page.

I'm sorry I haven't included any real answer in this post, because I don't know exactly what you want, and the details on that other link are very long.